# Quick smoke not animating the fire and the smoke

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to generate smoke in Blender using the quick smoke effect but it was not working. What I had done was that I added a plane into my scene, went on 'objects'- 'quick effects'- selected the emitter and changed the flow type to Fire + Smoke and then when I hit play, I see the smoke appear but it is not moving upwards. I'm also wondering how can I make the smoke appear on a specific frame.

[image]

A picture of the emitter and the settings.

[image]
A picture of the outer box and its settings.

[image]

Comment: I tried the steps you gave but couldn't replicate the problem about fire not moving upwards.try increasing the density and the temperature difference,also try setting the source and the normal to 20 in your flow object.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, all I got was an extra layer of the same smoke. I'll add my blender file in just in case no one mind checking it for me.

Comment: Here is the blender file: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1406" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1406/)

Comment: I just downloaded your file, selected the domain object and baked the dynamics and [here is the result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bQSFF.png). also i think you modified the wrong flow object, there is a plane under the domain that may be causing you problems.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Turns out I just needed to bake the domain!.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm also wondering how can I make the smoke appear on a specific frame.

You can limit the simulation to a range of frames by setting the *start* and  *end*  frames under smoke cahe.
*you need to save your project to use the smoke cache.*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set key frames for the eye and render icon deciding when they are visible and invisible during the scene.
This is the easiest and laziest method
Using the smoke cache alone will not make the smoke disappear the smoke will just freeze.

A better option for a final animation is to set a key frame for the density value in the smoke setting for the flow object

[image]

That way you can make the smoke die out on its own if that is what you want by setting a keyframe for the density value to hit zero at a certain frame

Comment: I just now realized that this is a post from a long time ago but i found it somewhere around what i thought was the recent posts page so my mistake